# how to place SMTP configuration on a separate file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, email, actionmailer

I'm configuring my app to send emails through gmail smtp, so I'm writing the `action_mailer` setup in the `production.rb` file.

Though I don't want to have my gmail credentials written in the `production.rb` file, which is git versioned.

this is what I have made so far:

in production rb:

```
  require "SmtpData"

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'my server's ip'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    enable_starttls_auto: "true",
    address: SmtpData::ADDRESS,
    port: SmtpData::PORT,
    domain: "pjforex.com",
    authentication: :plain,
    :user_name            => SmtpData::USER,
    :password             => SmtpData::PASS
  }
```

then I created `config/initializers/smtp_data.rb` containing:

```
class SmtpData
  USER = 'user@gmail.com'
  PASS = 'password'
  ADDRESS = "smtp.gmail.com"
  PORT = "587"
end
```

But when my capistrano tries to precompile the assets, I get :

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SmtpData
```

any clue on how to solve this. or better approach to this issue?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your configuration in a file excluded from Git but shared between deployments. Assuming you are using Capistrano 3, it would be something like this:

1) On your server create a file `shared/config/smtp.yml` (using YAML is not something crucial, but it's just cleaner for configs) in Capistrano root folder with the following content:

```
user: user@gmail.com
pass: your_password
address: smtp.gmail.com
port: 587
```

2) Add this file to your `linked_files` in `config/deploy.rb` (ideally, `config/database.yml` should be stored this way too):

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/smtp.yml}
```

3) Read SMTP config in `production.rb` from `config/smtp.yml`.

4) You can also have `config/smtp.yml` locally for your development environment, but don't forget to add it to your `.gitignore` then.

Comment: interesting, would I be then able to refer to the files via usual fetch name?

Comment: @dongiulio You mean get a list of linked files from another Capistrano task? Sure, why not. Or something else?

Comment: I meant, how do I reference these variables to link them to the right configurations?

Comment: `smtp_config = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/smtp.yml")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `production.rb` gets loaded before `smtp_data.rb`, which is why `production.rb` isn't able to access the class you have defined.

One solution we use, to keep sensitive credentials out of our git versions, is to create (as in your example) `production.rb.template` and add this to your git repository. This file is pretty much a copy of what you currently have for `production.rb`, except that you would have placeholders for where credentials should go.  For example,

```
:username => USERNAME GOES HERE
```

Then, we remove `production.rb` from the repository (and, optionally, set it to be ignored by git). When you check out your local copy of the repository, you copy `production.rb.template` as `production.rb`, and you fill in the credential information. This will only exist in your local deployment and would not be pushed to git.

Comment: hello, thanks but I'm not sure how this would work with Capistrano, that deploys from the git repository, and uses as production.rb whatever is in the repo. how do you deal with that?